# If $(m,n)=1$ then $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv0\pmod {mn}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, arithmetic-functions

> Show that if $(m,n)=1$ then $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv0\pmod {mn}$

I tried, $(m,n)=1$ then, Euler theorem we have $m^{\phi (n)}\equiv1\pmod n$ and $n^{\phi (m)}\equiv1\pmod m$. But I could not continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done

Observe that  $$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod m$$

Similarly, $$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod n$$

$$\implies m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod{\text{ lcm}(m,n)}$$

Comment: $\text{lcm}(m,n)=\frac{mn}{(m,n)}=mn$, with $(m,n)=1$.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, I left that for you:)

Comment: Then it is shown that $$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{mn}$$ but the question asks to show that the sum is congruent to $0\pmod {mn}$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, have you understood my method? Then answer will validate the question

Comment: I can not see the end of the demonstration.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, replace lcm$(m,n)$ with $mn$ what you have derived

Comment: I still can not see.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee See again second marcelolpjunior comment.

Comment: @Cortizol, have you noticed my second comment?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior I think in your problem is $\equiv 1$, not $\equiv 0$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes I did.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior,  
Observe that  $$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv0\pmod m$$ would imply  $$n^{\phi(m)}\equiv0\pmod m$$ which implies $m,n$ must common divisor $>1$

Comment: The question is just:

> Assuming that $(m, n) = 1$, show that $$m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv 0\pmod {mn}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod {m}$ not? (Euler theorem)

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, yes.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380510/proving-the-congruence-pq-1qp-1-equiv-1-pmodpq

Comment: @labbhattacharjee You put 0 in his penultimate comment.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, I wrote "would imply "

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Probably my translator left to be desired. But then you think my question is not correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11837/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-marcelolpjunior)

Answer (score 2):

First, one note: your RHS should be $1$, not $0$.

Given that: you've already shown that $m^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$, and it's easy what $n^{\phi(m)}$ equals $\pmod n$; this allows you to compute $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\pmod n$.  Do the same $\pmod m$, and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem (along with the fact that $\mathop{GCD}(m,n)=1$) to derive your result.

Comment: My text assures me that $m^{\phi(n)}+n^{\phi(m)}\equiv0\pmod{mn}$

Comment: If your text tells you that then your text is wrong, and that's very easy to show; just choose, e.g., $m=2$ (with $\phi(m)=1$) and $n=3$ (with $\phi(n)=2)$.

Comment: Correct, very good. Thank you!